# Integração Oracle10g com Sql Server 2008 via JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle

Preciso de uma ajuda, eu tenho um sistema que faz integração entre Oracle com Sql Server,  isso funcionava perfeitamente porém o Sql Server era 2000, foi atualizado para Sql Server 2008,  utilizava os driver do jdbc 2000, agora subi através do loadjava o jdbc 4.0( sqljdbc.jar/sqljdbc4.jar), porém quando faço o teste no sistema , não inseri no Sql Server, mas não apresenta erros, abaixo está a class,  tem alguma coisa que precisa mudar nela depois do upgrade do Sql Sever?

```
import java.sql.*;
//import javax.sql.*;
import javax.naming.*;

public class DataTransf
{
    private static Connection connFcl;


    ////    Connect    ////

    public static boolean Connect(String strConn)
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");
}
        catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfex)
        {
            System.err.println("Failed to load JDBC driver.");
            cnfex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            connFcl = DriverManager.getConnection(strConn);

            // exemplo: "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://srv0001:1433;User=User;Password=PASSWORD;DatabaseName=DATABASE"

        }
        catch(SQLException sqlex)
        {
            System.err.println("Unable to connect to FCL.");
            sqlex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }


    ////    ShutDown    ////

    public static boolean ShutDown()
    {
        try
        {
            connFcl.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException sqlex)
        {
            System.err.println("Unable to disconnect FCL.");
            sqlex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }


    ////    Procedure    ////

    public static int Procedure(String strCmd)
    {
        Statement stmtFcl;
        ResultSet rs;
        int iRet = 0;

        try
        {
             // System.out.println(strCmd);    // debug

            stmtFcl = connFcl.createStatement();
            rs = stmtFcl.executeQuery(strCmd);

            if(rs.next())
            {
                iRet = rs.getInt("Numero_Erro");
                if(rs.wasNull()) iRet = 0;
            }

            rs.close();
            stmtFcl.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException sqlex)
        {
            sqlex.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }

        return iRet;
    }


    ////    Exec    ////

    public static int Exec(String strCmd, String strConn)
    {
        int iRet;

        if(!Connect(strConn)) return -1;
        iRet = Procedure(strCmd);
        ShutDown();

        return iRet;
    }


    ////    main    ////

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        if(args.length == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("Resultado: " + Exec(args[0], args[1]));
        }
        else System.out.println("Usage:  DataTransf strCmd strConn");
    }
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->


    import java.sql.*;
    //import javax.sql.*;
    import javax.naming.*;

    public class DataTransf
    {
        private static Connection connFcl;


        ////    Connect    ////

        public static boolean Connect(String strConn)
        {
            try
            {
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");
    }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfex)
            {
                System.err.println("Failed to load JDBC driver.");
                cnfex.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

            try
            {
                connFcl = DriverManager.getConnection(strConn);

                // exemplo: "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://srv0001:1433;User=User;Password=PASSWORD;DatabaseName=DATABASE"

            }
            catch(SQLException sqlex)
            {
                System.err.println("Unable to connect to FCL.");
                sqlex.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }


        ////    ShutDown    ////

        public static boolean ShutDown()
        {
            try
            {
                connFcl.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException sqlex)
            {
                System.err.println("Unable to disconnect FCL.");
                sqlex.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }


        ////    Procedure    ////

        public static int Procedure(String strCmd)
        {
            Statement stmtFcl;
            ResultSet rs;
            int iRet = 0;

            try
            {
                 // System.out.println(strCmd);    // debug

                stmtFcl = connFcl.createStatement();
                rs = stmtFcl.executeQuery(strCmd);

                if(rs.next())
                {
                    iRet = rs.getInt("Numero_Erro");
                    if(rs.wasNull()) iRet = 0;
                }

                rs.close();
                stmtFcl.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException sqlex)
            {
                sqlex.printStackTrace();
                return -1;
            }

            return iRet;
        }


        ////    Exec    ////

        public static int Exec(String strCmd, String strConn)
        {
            int iRet;

            if(!Connect(strConn)) return -1;
            iRet = Procedure(strCmd);
            ShutDown();

            return iRet;
        }


        ////    main    ////

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            if(args.length == 2)
            {
                System.out.println("Resultado: " + Exec(args[0], args[1]));
            }
            else System.out.println("Usage:  DataTransf strCmd strConn");
        }
    }
```